# Shannon equation for a noiseless signal

Tags: telecommunication

What will be the Shannon equation for a noiseless signal?
Means if noise will be 0 then what will be the value of signal to noise ratio(S/N)?

Answer (score 0):

SNR would be infinity and you would have theoretical infinite transmission rate. But you always have noise, you know.